# Github workflow recommends archive before upload. How do I do that?

Tags: angular, github, azure-web-app-service

Warning: There are over 10,000 files in this artifact, consider creating an archive before upload to improve the upload performance

I have a boilerplate Angular app and use GitHub as a repository to upload to an Azure App Service.

I receive the title message. How do I add in the Angular project code that I want the artifacts to be archived before upload? At the current rate it would take me 45 minutes to publish an app update.

There is this post https://github.community/t/upload-artifact-dir-is-very-slow/173738/2 that provides a solution but I'm not sure how I would go about it?

EDIT:
An update.

I actually wrote the conditional so I could get past the upload artifact.

```
uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
  if: failure()
  with:
    name: node-app
    path: .
```